# Running ember.js application and node.js backend in grunt server

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, express, gruntjs

I am working on an application which has ember.js at frontend and node.js + express.js at backend. The ember.js front is based on yeoman generated template.

During development, how can I run backend and front application in same server and achieve 'liverreload'. The yeoman generated grunt.js file only runs ember application in liverreload enabled server. I dont want to runt one server for front end and one for back end.

P.S. In production version, I am starting node server and serving ember application via express static directory.

Below is the my node/express code:

```
var gzippo = require('gzippo');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
    app.use(express.logger('dev'));
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(app.router);
    app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/dist")); // built ember application is deployed in this dir
});

app.configure('development', function(){
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.url);
    console.log('__dirname : %s', __dirname);
    next();
});

app.post('/', function(req, res, next){
    req.method = "GET";
    next();
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 9000;
var host = 'localhost.com'
app.listen(port, host, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
});
```

There is no change in yeoman generated grunt.js file. Please guide me how I can achieve above explained scenario.

Thanks

Comment: check out this grunt plugin: https://github.com/blai/grunt-express , I actually have to do something like this ad well, maybe this week. Add that to your 'server' task.

Comment: Did you ever find an elegant solution to your problem?

Comment: Not yet. What about you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a client+server-side MVC JS framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935171/is-there-a-clientserver-side-mvc-js-framework)